# Replacing the wait command with the every command

Tags: netlogo, wait

```
to enemy-shoot
  every 2
  [
    ask one-of turtles with [ctrl = "enemy"]
    [
    hatch 1
    [
      set shape "dot"
      set ctrl "enemy-projectile"
      set size 2
      set color red
      set ycor ycor - 2
    ]
      let enemy-bullet any? turtles with [ctrl = "enemy-projectile"]
      ask turtles with [ctrl = "enemy-projectile"]
      [
        repeat 80
        [
          every 0.1
          [
            let ecollisions other turtles with [ctrl = "player" and distance myself < 1]
            if any? ecollisions
            [
              ask other turtles with [ctrl = "player" and distance myself < 1] [die]
              die
            ]
            bk 0.5
            wait .01
            if ycor = -16 [die]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

This works well enough for me to shoot and collision detect, but the wait command I use for this pauses the entire script. I want to replace it using the every command as it is local compared to wait, but I do not know how I should use it.

Comment: I suspect you have gone off track here. If you don't want your model to pause, then you shouldn't be using `wait`, and `every` doesn't really help. Clock advance is done with `tick`.

Comment: Agree: don't use `every`, don't use `wait`. Use `tick` and if your game is running too fast, limit the frame rate in the view settings.